# tuneup application memory management

Tags: memory-usage

I have couple of systems 75% the memory used for buffer and the rest by applicaion. I have a monitoring tool alert me for high memory usage be cause the system used 90% aavailable memory, based on my reading some documents,  the space used by cache available for application when need it, if that the case, the alert should be ignored the low memory alert or the cache usage can be limit?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct, you should tune your alerting system so that it alerts when the used memory is high as memory used as cache is returned to processes when they request it.